# MonoDevelop - Targetting iPhone Simulator 4.2 rather than 4.3

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, llvm, monogame

I'm running it to a MonoTouch + MonoGame sample with MonoDevelop, but I'm running into an LLVM error. I ran into this with XCode 4+ as well, and worked around it by switching the deployment target from 4.3 to 4.2... can this be done in MonoDevelop?  How?

TIA

Comment: Upgrading the MonoDevelop Beta 2.6 beta 3 fixes this, by allowing you to easily target different SDK versions.  For those that run into to this you can target different SDK versions by...

Comment: ... selecting Project -> iPhone Simulator Target \ iPhone Simulator 4.2.  Cheers!

Comment: You should answer your own question and mark as the answer.